# Finding closest points in 3d space in R

Tags: r, pca

I have this dataframe `mydf` with three eigenvectors from my PCA. I want to determine which rowname is close to one another based on three eigenvectors (columns `e.1`,`e.2` and `e.3`). Mathematically, I could use euclidian distance formula as shown below:

[image]

Then, I need to plot this to individual points and be able to determine the relationship from the plot.

```
mydf<-
structure(c("-0.013692", "-0.012993", "-0.014427", "-0.01494", 
"-0.014326", "-0.013538", "-0.00877", "-0.011291", "-0.007758", 
"-0.010291", "-0.006252", "-0.009363", "0.002385", "-0.000187", 
"0.003553", "-0.000317", "0.002357", "0.003262"), .Dim = c(6L, 
3L), .Dimnames = list(c("1749742002_A", "1749742086_A", "1749742184_A", 
"1749742205_A", "1749742207_A", "1749742218_A"), c("e.1", "e.2", 
"e.3")))
```

Comment: What are you unable to do?

Comment: @Codoremifa I could not figure out how to put this in code. I may be able to use tapply and make a new column with distance. Then I don't know how I can plot it and use functions like legend or identify to determine the relationship.

Comment: @Codoremifa There must be some trick to get the relationship, such as by pointing with the mouse, it should be able to show the relationship as first closest and then second and so on..

Comment: Won't your distance be a matrix and not a column? Or are you considering dynamically calculating distance every time a point is picked? Native R doesn't allow interactivity on plots. You need to use `shiny` with `ggplot2` at the least to produce any interactivity.

Comment: @Codoremifa That's right! It will be a matrix. Plus I would also like to dynamically calculate the distance every time a point is picked.

Comment: Picking is in 2D, your plot is in 3D. How does the pick know where in space it is?

Comment: @DieterMenne Both plot and picking is in 2D. It will only make use of the distance calculated from 3 eigenvectors.

Comment: If you are able to calculate the distances, you can use the examples here (http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/#interactive-plots) to try and get your plot up.

Comment: @Codoremifa Thank you for the help.